# Auth using jsonwebtoken(why user is equal to req.user)

Tags: authentication, request, jwt, access-token

here is the code for auth using jsonwebtoken which i got from youtube tutorial,
why req.user =user

```
import jwt from "jsonwebtoken";
const auth = (req, res, next) => {
  try {
    const token = req.header("Authorization");
    if (!token) return res.status(400).json({ msg: "Invalid Authentication" });
    jwt.verify(token, process.env.SECRET_JWT, (err, user) => {
      if (err) return res.status(400).json({ msg: "Authentication Failed" });
      req.user = user;
      next();
    });
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You set `req.user = user` so that you can actually use this in a later middleware function called after this one (triggered by `next()`.
If you do not do something similar to this, you would not know who the user is in the next middleware function or you would have to verify/decode the token every time you need to know who the user is.